# Working with a sql script in a Flask application

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, flask

I have created a structure of a basic Flask application and I need guidance with executing a sql script. My folder structure is this:

-simpleblog (name of app)

```
  flask (contains the virtual environment, 3 folders)
  app
    static (css, js)
    templates (html)
    __init__.py
  config.py
  run.py
```

I have a sql script with the definition of one table, and I don't know where to place it and how to execute it. I know sqlite3 is part of python, but must I install anything else?

Comment: what is the SQL script ? can you please share ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this tutorial from flask website that explains how to use a sqllite database and execute sql scripts along with a suggested folder structure. Usually, you can create a schema.sql file and put it in the main app folder. In your example, you can put it as:

```
app
    static (css, js)
    templates (html)
    __init__.py
    config.py
    run.py
    schema.sql # your sql script
```

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/tutorial/schema/#tutorial-schema

To create the initial database, use this. But you do need to install sqllite3 first.

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/tutorial/dbinit/#tutorial-dbinit

Basically, it lets you create your initial database by running the following command:

```
sqlite3 /tmp/flaskr.db < schema.sql
```

Lets understand the above command. we have the database creation scripts (CREATE,DROP etc.) in schema.sql. We take that as a input to the sqlite3 executable and create the database at /tmp/flaskr.db. Note: you might need to run the following command first to generate a blank flaskr.db file

```
touch /tmp/flaskr.db
```

Comment: This is the tutorial that I follow, I was reading its pdf version and I missed the bit about where to place the file. Now, regarding executing the script I cannot understand the following          

"Such a schema can be created by piping the schema.sql file into the sqlite3 command as follows:"

how do I install sqlite3 in my virtual environment? I tried with pip and failed.

Comment: Ok I made to work, thank you very much; let me ask you, what is the point of putting this db file in a tmp folder? I thought this is a database driven app, so the db file is of primary importance? Also, is there a GUI tool to query this database, just for convenience.

Comment: good question. I think the tutorial just uses the tmp folder to demonstrate but realistically, you will not. the tutorial lets you delete and re-create the db and hnce using a tmp folder i guess.